# have the caption of a figure overlaping the figure (floatrow)

Tags: captions, floatrow

i try to overlap the caption of a figure with the figure itself as shown in the picture:
[image: mockup of the desired outcome]

the picture is only mockup of what i want to achieve.
i use the following code to insert the image and caption and i have the *floatrow* package included:

```
{\floatsetup{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={bottom,right}}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{experimental/ec-cell-schematic}
    \caption{Schematic of the single compartiment cell used for the electrochemical measurements.\\a) Reference electrode\\b) Counter electrode\\c) RDE Shaft / holder\\d) GC-RDE tip (black square)\\e) Gas overflow inlet\\f) Gas tube with frit for saturation}
    \label{fig:ec-cell-schematic}
\end{figure}}
```

is this possible to achieve? i am thinking about maybe negative margins or something along those lines but i have no idea where to start with that...

---

As requested:

Full working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}


\begin{document}

{\floatsetup{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={bottom,right}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ec-cell-schematic}
    \caption{Schematic of the single compartiment cell used for the electrochemical measurements.\\a) Reference electrode\\b) Counter electrode\\c) RDE Shaft / holder\\d) GC-RDE tip (black square)\\e) Gas overflow inlet\\f) Gas tube with frit for saturation}
\end{figure}}

{\floatsetup{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={bottom,right}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ec-cell-schematic-additionalcontent}
    \caption{Schematic of the single compartiment cell used for the electrochemical measurements.\\a) Reference electrode\\b) Counter electrode\\c) RDE Shaft / holder\\d) GC-RDE tip (black square)\\e) Gas overflow inlet\\f) Gas tube with frit for saturation}
\end{figure}}

\end{document}
```

and the two images, one being wider and having a textbox where the additional content will be (the final graphic is not done yet and depends on the outcome of this)

i.stack.imgur.com/mFvjj.png

i.stack.imgur.com/GGVaV.png

(posting the links in plain text because i have not enough reputation to post more than two links... this seems a little bit too restrictive IMO but hey...)

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code and a graphic file (I don't have on such shape at hand)?

Comment: i added the additional info as an edit to my post. thanks for taking a look into it. you will need to rename the images since imgur renamed them to gibberish, and i could not post them as links because of the weird reputation restriction...

Comment: I don't understand. Your code compiles fine. Is the part of the figure above the caption your problem? None of the images you posted has this part, so I can't test that situation.

Comment: ok, maybe i was not clear anough. the code i posted technically works fine, but i want to achieve a result, similar to the very first picture in my question: the caption for the picture should "overlap" the picture itself in the area where the actual picture is blank.

i then added the following picture:
i.stack.imgur.com/GGVaV.png
having a black frame where the future content should be. i will quickly do another mockup to clarify. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Still  not very clear. In my way of expressing it, part of the picture will be too wide, so the picture area and the caption area will overlap?

Comment: yes exactly. that should clarify:
http://i.imgur.com/GydvYuA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple: *scale*  your figures instead of adjusting their widths. As the figures did not have the same width, adjusting them to the same width induced different scalings. So use the same scaling for both figures (it seems to be ~ 0.25), then fool LaTeX  putting them in a box of width 0.4\textwidth:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

{\floatsetup{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={bottom,right}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ec-cell-schematic}}
    \caption{Schematic of the single compartiment cell used for the electrochemical measurements.\\a) Reference electrode\\b) Counter electrode\\c) RDE Shaft / holder\\d) GC-RDE tip (black square)\\e) Gas overflow inlet\\f) Gas tube with frit for saturation}
\end{figure}}

{\floatsetup{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={bottom,right}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.25]{ec-cell-schematic-additionalcontent}}
    \caption{Schematic of the single compartiment cell used for the electrochemical measurements.\\a) Reference electrode\\b) Counter electrode\\c) RDE Shaft / holder\\d) GC-RDE tip (black square)\\e) Gas overflow inlet\\f) Gas tube with frit for saturation}
\end{figure}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thats exactly what i wanted to achieve. thanks for trying (and succeding) to figure out what my thoughts where. i try to be more specific in the future.